# Windows 8 XAML/C# - How to draw dynamic elements on a canvas?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, canvas, windows-8

I have canvas control I'm using for a graph and need to be able to dynamically add a variable amount of data points to it. Maybe I'm not aware of a good control to do this type of thing with but I was trying to do it with a GridView as such:

```
<Canvas x:Name="GraphPointsAndLines" Canvas.ZIndex="2">
        <GridView x:Name="gvDataPoints">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button IsEnabled="False" Canvas.Left="{Binding PointXValue}" Canvas.Top="{Binding PointYValue}" Content="{Binding Value}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonGraphPoint}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </Canvas>
```

But due to the nature of the gridview it's not recognizing that the child button elements are a part of any such canvas and just ends up stacking them on top of one another. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Any chance you could supply a quick rough picture of what you're after to help visualize the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

This could be interesting: [simple technique for databinding to position](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/139216/A-Simple-Technique-for-Data-binding-to-the-Positio).

Basically, have an items control with an items source and apply the data template, set its items panel and apply the items container style.